# yolov5 reduce the frame rate while using the camera as a source?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, streaming, yolov5

I am working on a project to predict the pedestrian path using a history and so on so i am using this paper and trying to run and implement the missing annotation in this
https://github.com/JunweiLiang/Multiverse/blob/master/SimAug

so i used yolov5 to solve this issue but i found that the fps is 30 and it takes a long time to process all these frames so i wanted to decrease the fps so for example it take only 2 frames per second and run the pipeline

(detection --> tracking) --> segmentation --> prediction and so on.

so basically here is what i did

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import datetime
import queue
from threading import Thread

# global variables
stop_thread = False             # controls thread execution


def start_capture_thread(cap, queue):
    # global stop_thread
    i=0
    # continuously read fames from the camera
    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()
        queue.put(img)
        # cv2.imwrite('Images/frame{:d}.jpg'.format(i), img)
        i=i+1
        # if (stop_thread):
        #     break


def main():
    global stop_thread

    # create display window
    cv2.namedWindow("webcam", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    # initialize webcam capture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    # retrieve properties of the capture object
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print('* Capture width:', cap_width)
    print('* Capture height:', cap_height)
    print('* Capture FPS:', cap_fps)

    # create a queue
    frames_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

    # start the capture thread: reads frames from the camera (non-stop) and stores the result in img
    t = Thread(target=start_capture_thread, args=(cap, frames_queue,), daemon=True) # a deamon thread is killed when the application exits
    t.start()

    # initialize time and frame count variables
    last_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    frames = 0
    cur_fps = 0
    i=0
    while (True):
        if (frames_queue.empty()):
            continue
        
        if i%5 !=0 :
            _ = frames_queue.get()
            i+=1
            continue

        # blocks until the entire frame is read
        frames += 1

        # # measure runtime: current_time - last_time
        # delta_time = datetime.datetime.now() - last_time
        # elapsed_time = delta_time.total_seconds()

        # # compute fps but avoid division by zero
        # if (elapsed_time != 0):
        #     cur_fps = np.around(frames / elapsed_time, 1)

        # retrieve an image from the queue
        img = frames_queue.get()
        cv2.imwrite('Images/frame{:d}.jpg'.format(i), img)
        i+=1
        # for i in range(10):
        #     _ = frames_queue.get()
        #     i+=1
        # TODO: process the image here if needed

        # draw FPS text and display image
        # if (img is not None):
        #     cv2.putText(img, 'FPS: ' + str(cur_fps), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #     cv2.imshow("webcam", img)

        # wait 1ms for ESC to be pressed
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if (key == 27):
            stop_thread = True
            break

    # release resources
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and it works so i want to use this in the track.py in yolov5 instead of the

```
dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt and not jit)
```

but i can't modify it as it used in the code like this

```
for frame_idx, (path, img, im0s, vid_cap, s) in enumerate(dataset):
```

but i couldn't full understand this line

so i wanted to modify the LoadStreams function in here https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/utils/datasets.py but i am kinda stuck here